# Replace character in string with the corresponding character in a different string

Tags: r, string

For example, I have two different strings of the same length:

```
          #string 1
MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNGDLXKXLHERQPRIAAL

          #string 2
MELQSRPEALAVELARHQNGDLKKQLHERQPRIAAL
```

I would like to replace the `X` in the first string with the corresponding character in the second string.

I could do this by hand - but the real strings are several thousand characters long, with the `X` characters interspersed randomly.

Is there any way to do this in R? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
string1 <- "MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNGDLXKXLHERQPRIAAL"
string2 <- "MELQSRPEALAVELARHQNGDLKKQLHERQPRIAAL"

# Convert strings to character vectors
string1_chars <- unlist(strsplit(string1, ""))
string2_chars <- unlist(strsplit(string2, ""))

# Replace 'X' in string1 with corresponding characters from string2
string1_chars[string1_chars == 'X'] <- string2_chars[string1_chars == 'X']

# Combine characters back into a string
result <- paste(string1_chars, collapse = "")

print(result) # MELQSRPEALAVELARHQNGDLKKQLHERQPRIAAL
```

Answer (score 1):

With `utf8ToInt`, `intToUtf8`, and `collapse::setv`:

```
string1 <- "MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNGDLXKXLHERQPRIAAL"
string2 <- "MELQSRPEALAVELARHQNGDLKKQLHERQPRIAAL"

intToUtf8(collapse::setv(utf8ToInt(string1), utf8ToInt("X"), utf8ToInt(string2)))
#> [1] "MELQSRPEALAVELARHQNGDLKKQLHERQPRIAAL"
```

Benchmarking:

```
s1 <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(1, 1e5, '[A-Z]')
s2 <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(1, 1e5, '[A-W, Y-Z]')

floop <- function(s1, s2) {
  inx <- gregexpr("X", s1) |> unlist()
  for(i in inx) {
    substr(s1, i, i) <- substr(s2, i, i)
  }
  s1
}

fsplit <- function(s1, s2) {
  string1_chars <- unlist(strsplit(s1, ""))
  string2_chars <- unlist(strsplit(s2, ""))
  string1_chars[string1_chars == 'X'] <- string2_chars[string1_chars == 'X']
  paste(string1_chars, collapse = "")
}

bench::mark(
  floop = floop(s1, s2),
  fsplit = fsplit(s1, s2),
  int = intToUtf8(collapse::setv(utf8ToInt(s1), utf8ToInt("X"), utf8ToInt(s2)))
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 floop        12.59s   12.59s    0.0795  366.17MB     1.19
#> 2 fsplit       8.88ms   9.93ms   96.8        5.4MB    11.9 
#> 3 int         649.7µs  977.2µs  953.        1.53MB    36.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.
Find where the `"X"`'s are with `gregexpr`. Then replace those characters by the characters in the same positions with `substr` and `its replacement version,` substr<-`.

```r
string1 <- "MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNGDLXKXLHERQPRIAAL"
string2 <- "MELQSRPEALAVELARHQNGDLKKQLHERQPRIAAL"

inx <- gregexpr("X", string1) |> unlist()
for(i in inx) {
  substr(string1, i, i) <- substr(string2, i, i)
}
string1
#> [1] "MELQSRPEALAVELARHQNGDLKKQLHERQPRIAAL"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>